# Python Window Scheduler File Output

Tags: python, file, output, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have the following python code and it runs just fine if I run it manually.  When I go to schedule it in Window's scheduler it doesn't work. Any idea why?

```
#Data
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import os
import sys
import traceback

#Pandas and Numpy
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import numpy as np

#Set Directory
#print('\nRead in data file')
indirname = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop'
outdirname = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop'

#Read in file
data_file = os.path.join(indirname, r'File Name.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(data_file, sheet_name='Sheet2', skiprows=range(1))

df.to_excel('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test5.xlsx')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your script is fine than you can check your python.exe location using `where python` command in your command prompt then paste the path in `Program/script` dilogue box then provide full path of your python file in `add arguments` with double quotes. e.g. `"C:\user\name\folder\file.py"` and empty your start in (optional)

[image]

Comment: Hello. I have tried that and it doesn't work. If I run my code manually it works. Any other ideas? Thanks for the idea.

Comment: You work on same local PC or any other server

Comment: And one more thing change your file name remove space add underscore File_build.py or build.py.

Comment: I can face same issue when I used - like All-train-ARIMA.py and it doesn't work then I remove - and replace with underscore.

Comment: Tried both of those changing the name and adding underscores